# I want to backup existing files in FTP every time before deploy, can this be done using Jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, ftp, backup

I have a MVC web applications project we use FTP(Filezilla) to host. In Jenkins i know we have plugin to Deploy files to FTP but every time before that i want to backup existing files in FTP, can this be done using Jenkins pipeline. I am Sorry if I am not clear.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should be able to use the [Publish Over FTP plugin](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/publish-over-ftp/#ftppublisher-send-build-artifacts-over-ftp) for this. You can use something like `curl` to download the files from the FTP.

```
curl -O ftp://server/path/to/file
```

Another option is [SSH2 Easy plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/ssh2easy/) which allows FTP file upload/download.